# Landscape table and page numbering

Tags: tables, rotating, landscape, page, number

I have a problem with a landscape table and the page numbers. I have already tried several things. Maybe someone can help me fix it.

```
    \afterpage{%
    \clearpage
    \begin{landscape}
        \subsection{Lorem Ipsum}
        \begin{table}[htb]
            \centering
            \caption{Lorem Ipsum}
            \label{tab:LoremIpsum}
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcccc}
                \hline
                \textbf{Lorem} & \textbf{Ipsum} & \textbf{Dolor} & \textbf{Sit} & \textbf{Amet} \\
                & & \textbf{Lorem} & \textbf{Ipsum} & \textbf{Dolor} \\
                \hline
                Lorem & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Ipsum & 3 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
                Dolor & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Sit & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Amet & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Lorem & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Ipsum & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Dolor & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Sit & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Amet & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Lorem & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Ipsum & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Dolor & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Sit & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Amet & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                Lorem & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
                 Ipsum & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
            Dolor & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
            Sit & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
            Amet & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
            \hline
            \textbf{Consectetur} & & & & \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{landscape}
}
```

The page number is displayed in the left corner and rotated incorrectly. I would like to see the page number in the right corner without rotation.

Thank you

Comment: you have not provided an example that shows your problem, the landcape environment from `lscape` package (I assume, although you do not say how you defined `landscape`) is designed to rotate the page body leaving page head and foot in portrait. so the position of the page number depends on the page style you have not shown